# How to cutoff left and right part of sentence using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Converting the sentence into a list of words, then finding the index of root string should do the stuff:

```
sentence = "lack of association between the promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic scoliosis"
root = "mtnr1a"

try:
    words = sentence.split()
    n = words.index(root)
    cutoff = ' '.join(words[n-4:n+5])
except ValueError:
    cutoff = None

print(cutoff)
```

Result:

```
promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic
```

How to to it in pandas dataframe?

I try:

```
sentence = data['sentence'] 
root = data['rootword'] 
def cutOff(sentence,root): 
   try: 
      words = sentence.str.split() 
      n = words.index(root) 
      cutoff = ' '.join(words[n-4:n+5]) 
except ValueError: 
      cutoff = None 
      return cutoff 
data.apply(cutOff(sentence,root),axis=1)
```

But it doesn't working...

Edit:

How to cut sentence after 4 strings after root word, when root word is on first position in sentence, and when root word is on last position in sentence?
For example:

```
sentence = "mtnr1a lack of association between the promoter polymorphism of the gene and adolescent idiopathic scoliosis"
out if root in first position:
"mtnr1a lack of association between"
out if root in last position:
"lack of association between the promoter polymorphism of the gene and adolescent idiopathic scoliosis"
"adolescent idiopathic scoliosis mtnr1a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two minor tweaks in your code should fix your issue:

Firstly, calling [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on your dataframe applies the function to the values in each row of the DataFrame on which it is called.

You don't have to pass in the columns as inputs to the functions and it doesn't make sense to call `sentence.str.split()`. Inside the `cutOff()` function `sentence` is just a regular string (not the column).

Change your function to:

```
def cutOff(sentence,root): 
    try: 
        words = sentence.split()  # this is the line that was changed
        n = words.index(root) 
        cutoff = ' '.join(words[n-4:n+5]) 
    except ValueError: 
        cutoff = None 
    return cutoff
```

Next you just have to specify the columns that will be the inputs to your function- you can do this using `lambda`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: cutOff(x["sentence"], x["rootword"]), axis=1)
#0    promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and a...
#dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @pault !!! Do you know how to write code when my root word is on start or end of sentence and only cut left or right side of sentence?
For example root = aaaa1

'aaa1 here is very good sentence' -> out '... sentence'
'here is very good sentence aaa1' -> out 'here...'

Comment: I do not understand your desired output based on that comment. Please either [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49983773/edit) your question and explain it in more detail, or ask a new question.